# segmentation fault on end of function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

below you can find my full code (yes, I've changed this to make it buildeable for tests and short)

It basically has to read file /var/log/messages and write on teste.txt only the IP addresses it finds
It works well, but it never print the "parte 8\n" after run the function (check function main())
It always run the code well, print everything, except what has after function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> // htons e inet_addr
#ifndef __FAVOR_BSD
#   define __FAVOR_BSD
#endif
#include <netinet/udp.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define RANDOM() (int) random() % 255 +1

char * RetornaStringEntreStrings( char * primString, char * segString, char * stringao)
{
    char * posPrim = strstr(stringao, primString);
    if(posPrim <= 0)
    {
        return "";
    }
    posPrim += strlen(primString);

    char * posSeg = strstr(posPrim, segString);

    char * retorno;
    memcpy(retorno, posPrim, posSeg-posPrim);
    retorno[posSeg-posPrim] = 0;
    return retorno;
}

int ExisteIPnoArquivo(char *ip, char *arquivoNome)
{
    FILE *arquivo = fopen(arquivoNome, "r");
    char buffer[128];

    if(arquivo != NULL)
    {
        while(fgets(buffer, 128, arquivo))
        {
            if(strcmp(ip, buffer) == 0)
            {
                fclose(arquivo);
                return 1;
            }
        }
        fclose(arquivo); 
        return 0;
    }
    else
        printf("Nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo.\n");

    return 0;
}

void EscreverArquivo(char * string, char * arquivoNome)
{
    FILE *arquivo = fopen(arquivoNome, "a+");

    if(arquivo == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo!");
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(arquivo, "%s", string);
        fclose(arquivo);
    }
}

void SalvarLogsArquivo(char * arquivoNome)
{
    FILE *arquivo = fopen("/var/log/messages", "r");
    char buffer[512];

    // testa se o arquivo foi aberto com sucesso
    if(arquivo != NULL)
    {
        while(fgets(buffer, 512, arquivo))
        {
            char * IP = RetornaStringEntreStrings("SRC=", " ", buffer);
            if(strlen(IP) < 7)
                continue;

            strcat(IP, "\n");
            if(ExisteIPnoArquivo(IP, arquivoNome) == 0)
            {
                printf("Adicionando IP: %s", IP);
                EscreverArquivo(IP, arquivoNome);
            }
            else
                printf("IP ja encontrado: %s", IP);
        }
        fclose(arquivo); // libera o ponteiro para o arquivo
    }
    else
        printf("Nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo.");

    printf("End of Function (segmentation fault below will happen below)\n");
}


int main() 
{
    SalvarLogsArquivo("teste.txt");
    printf("After function, it doesn't run cuz it gets segmentation fault before\n");
}
```

Comment: `if(posPrim <= 0)` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Would be handy to know where the seg fault occurs

Comment: `posPrim <= 0` does not make sense. You cmpare a pointer against a _null pointer constant_ only for equality, not ordering. Also you should use the macro `NULL`, not the integer constant `0` in C.

Comment: if you want to test, you can find the /var/log/message I'm using here: http://pastebin.com/fKpepSaU

Comment: Thanks for the the posPrim <= 0 check. I changed it to:
  if(posPrim == NULL)
  {
   return "";
  }

But the segmentation fault continues

Comment: Don't return `""` and at other place a heap allocated variable. Be consistent, how will you know whether to `free()` the returned pointer? Also, use a debugger to find the exact line where the segmentation fault occurs. And use [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) it will help you even more to find the problem

Answer (score 4):

This is the cause

```
char * retorno;
memcpy(retorno, posPrim, posSeg-posPrim);
```

You didn't allocate memory for `retorno`, you need to with `malloc()`. Example

```
retorno = malloc(posSeg - posPrim + 1);
if (retorno != NULL)
{
    memcpy(retorno, posPrim, posSeg - posPrim);
    retorno[posSeg - posPrim] - '\0';
}
```

Comment: wow, you are awesom! But don't I need to use free() if I use malloc? The reason I didn't try malloc() is I wouldn't know when I should free() it, since the memory should be returned

Comment: You certainly have a problem in the first `return` in your code, you can't free a string literal, you probably should return `NULL` indicating failure and then it's always safe to `free()` the returned pointer.

Answer (score 2):

In your function `RetornaStringEntreStrings()` you copy data to an uninitialized pointer which might segfault (*in general it's **undefined behavior***):

```
 char * retorno;
 memcpy(retorno, posPrim, posSeg-posPrim);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the result that the code does not work properly is the same ;)